# AWS IoT , Basic ingest and rule names containing 'special' characters

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot

I am reading through https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-basic-ingest.html which seems to indicate that it's possible to trigger basic ingest using hierarchical topic names like $aws/rules/BuildingManager/Buildings/Building5/Floor2/Room201/Lights.

As far as I understand that requires creating a rule with a name like  'BuildingManager/Buildings/Building5/Floor2/Room201/Lights' but rule names cannot have '/' in their name.

I am sure I am missing something basic but I can't get my head around it.

All tips warmly welcomed!

Tx!

Peter

Answer (score 0):

I just found out it's really simple :)

Need to create the rule with the first part of the 'hierarchy' as the name.

When posting to an MQTT topic that has this name as a first part of the topic,  the rule triggers and the topic() function returns everything after the name.

Peter

Comment: As shown in this video that took us 15 minutes to recreate https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BmJnWOY1I2Q

Comment: Thanks for the video. Nice tooling you have there!

Comment: $1 / hour to rent on AWS Marketplace

Comment: Can you share your policy configuration? I cannot publish